# new line with variable in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, newline, combinations, line-breaks

When I use `"\n"` in my `print` function it gives me a syntax error in the following code

```
from itertools import combinations
a=[comb for comb in combinations(range(1,96+1),7) if sum(comb) == 42]
print (a "\n")
```

Is there any way to add new line in each combination?

Comment: Where are you using "\n"?

Comment: print (a "\n") like this @mprat

Comment: @user6234753 you make wrong concatenation of the string. Checkout [**this**](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/concatenation/string-concatenation-and-formatting-in-python)

Comment: Is this Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: okay @sємsєм I will check it

Comment: Python 3 @EdwardMinnix

Comment: This is unrelated to the problem, but doing combinations of numbers up to 97 and then keeping only those combinations that add up to 42 is a waste of processing time. On topic, I'm also not sure printing a `\n` after `a` will improve the readability... maybe you want to print a new line after each combination?

Comment: change the combination to a different number I just want to make every combination in new line  @PauloAlmeida

Comment: @user6234753 `for combination in a: print(combination)` will do what you want.

Comment: thank you so much @PauloAlmeida

Answer (score 7):

The `print` function already adds a newline for you, so if you just want to print followed by a newline, do (parens mandatory since this is Python 3):

```
print(a)
```

If the goal is to print the elements of `a` each separated by newlines, you can either loop explicitly:

```
for x in a:
    print(x)
```

or abuse star unpacking to do it as a single statement, using `sep` to split outputs to different lines:

```
print(*a, sep="\n")
```

If you want a blank line between outputs, not just a line break, add `end="\n\n"` to the first two, or change `sep` to `sep="\n\n"` for the final option.

Answer (score 3):

Two possibilities:

```
print "%s\n" %a
print a, "\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you:

I used 1,2...6 in my example and 2 length tuples with a combination sum of 7.

```
from itertools import combinations
a=["{0}\n".format(comb) for comb in combinations(range(1,7),2) if sum(comb) == 7]

print(a)
for thing in a:
    print(thing)
```

## Output

```
['(1, 6)\n', '(2, 5)\n', '(3, 4)\n']
(1, 6)

(2, 5)

(3, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

for me in the past something like print("\n",a) works.